# Pass email address to Mail::send function Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to pass a variable with the to email address into the Mail:send function and I'm getting the following error because it cannot read the variable within the function.

Undefined variable: to

```
 $data = array(
        "name"=>"Foo Bar"
    );

$to = "to@email.com";

Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) {
    $message->from('from@email.com', 'Name');
    $message->subject("Subject Name");
    $message->to($to);
});
```

How could i pass the email address into the send function as it won't be a static email address i would be sending emails to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the way PHP's anonymous functions work, you have to specifically indicate each variable that should be included in to the function's scope, using the `use` keyword.

```
Mail::send('mail', $data, function ($message) use ($to) {
    $message->from('from@email.com', 'Name');
    $message->subject("Subject Name");
    $message->to($to);
});
```

Here's [a link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-180) to more information in PHP's documentation.